# Вотемарк на звук

Tags: javascript, php

Можно ли с помощью php либо js накладывать на аудио-дорожку вотемарк ? Т.е. звук поверх звука независимо от формата, либо приведение (конвертация) формата к формату вотемарки. Если да, то есть ли библиотеки/функции для этого ?

Comment: Можно установить на сервере ffmpeg и запустить его с желаемыми опциями, например

Comment: @andreymal там же вроде только на video можно вотемарку кидать..или нет ?

Comment: ffmpeg умеет работать и со звуком тоже

Comment: Есть такая библиотека: github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg